# Batch file: extract part of a string with special chars

Tags: string, batch-file

**Short version**

Can somebody please help me extract from a string like this:

```
HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0892&SUBSYS_18492892&REV_1003\4&2120120&0&0001: Realtek High Definition Audio
```

only the part before second backslash (\):

```
HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0892&SUBSYS_18492892&REV_1003
```

The difficult part is that the digits are not constant and can be different, same goes for the total length of the string, the only constant is it has 2 slashes and I need the part before second slash (second slash and everything after it must be removed)

Thank you.

---

**Long version** *if you are interested*

I'm trying get a part of a string that returned by another application:

```
devcon.exe find "HDAUDIO\FUNC_01"
```

It returns something like this:

```
HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10DE&DEV_0018&SUBSYS_10DE0101&REV_1001\5&13022D22&0&0201: NVIDIA High Definition Audio
HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0892&SUBSYS_18492892&REV_1003\4&2120120&0&0001: Realtek High Definition Audio
HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10DE&DEV_0018&SUBSYS_10DE0101&REV_1001\5&13022D22&0&0101: NVIDIA High Definition Audio
3 matching device(s) found.
```

From these lines I need capture only one line:

```
HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0892&SUBSYS_18492892&REV_1003\4&2120120&0&0001: Realtek High Definition Audio
```

And from that line I need get only this part:

```
HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0892&SUBSYS_18492892&REV_1003
```

Unfortunately this line can be different on different systems, the only consistent part is the beginning:

```
HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_
```

and that it has two slashes.
This means the only key can be used to mach the string is the second backslash - anything after second "\" must be removed.

So far I'm able get the needed whole line, but I can't figure out how to extract the needed part out of that line:

```
@echo off
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`devcon.exe find "HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC"`) DO (
set string=%%F
set match=!string:HDAUDIO\FUNC_01^&VEN_10EC^&DEV_=!
if not !match!==!string! goto found
)
endlocal
:found
set str="%string%"
set id=!str:~1,-1!
set id=!id:^&=^^^&!
echo %id%
```

As an example here is the part for checking the code:

```
set string="HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0892&SUBSYS_18492892&REV_1003\4&2120120&0&0001: Realtek High Definition Audio"
set str=%string%
set id=!str:~1,-1!
set id=!id:^&=^^^&!
echo %id%
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@echo off
set "string=HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0892&SUBSYS_18492892&REV_1003\4&2120120&0&0001: Realtek High Definition Audio"
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=\" %%a in ("%string%") do echo "%%a\%%b"
```